# Swift -- Idiomatic equivalent to typeof in typealias

Tags: swift, protocols, typeof, idioms, type-alias

In Swift, I'm writing a custom `SequenceType` with a very simple `generate()` implementation:

```
func generate() -> Generator {
    return elements.keys.generate()
}
```

However, `Generator` is not an actual type -- it just refers to a `typealias`, which I have to manually specify elsewhere in my type.

Clicking through the declarations associated with `Dictionary`, the type of `elements.keys.generate()` seems to be complicated, and almost an implementation detail of the compiler.  I feel like the cleanest way to define my type alias would be something like

```
typealias Generator = typeof(elements.keys.generate())
```

However, Swift obviously has not `typeof` directive.  Is there any cleaner way to write my `typealias` than to go with the following ugly and slightly fragile code?

```
typealias Generator = LazyBidirectionalCollection<MapCollectionView<[Key : Value], Key>>.Generator
```

(Yes, I am aware that `Key` and `Value` have to be replaced with the types for my specific dictionary.  What those types are isn't important here, however).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing a custom `SequenceType` holding elements of type `Element`, you write your generator like this:

```
 public func generate () -> AnyGenerator<Element> {
    var generator = objs.keys.generate()
    return AnyGenerator {
      return generator.next ()
    }
  }
```

Because the above code is implemented in the scope of your `SequenceType,` the `Element` type is well known.  You those don't have to 'infer' the type from `objs.keys.generate()` you just use it as `Element`.

Comment: `GeneratorOf<T>` has been removed in Swift 2.0. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255249/swift-2-0-version-of-struct-generatoroft

Comment: Done. Thanks for updating. :)