# Swift 2.0 version of struct GeneratorOf<T>

Tags: generics, generator, sequence, swift2

It appears that `struct GeneratorOf<T> {…}` is not available in in Swift 2.0. Does anyone know what, if anything, replaces this struct?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GeneratorOf` was replaced by `AnyGenerator` but you have to call a global function instead of the initializer to make one:

```
anyGenerator(anotherGenerator)
anyGenerator{ /* pass "next function" (as closure) */ }
```

Comment: That was it. I didn't realize there was a global function for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 2 `GeneratorOf` is replaced by `class AnyGenerator<Element>`.